# User was removed... But from where?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-accounts, reputation-history

I have read the other questions here about 'user was removed'.  This is not a duplicate because I understand the mechanics of the hit and have taken the hit before (although on the main site).

[image]

You will see the decrement next to the aviation site.  The hit is 10 points. On to the question...

How could a user give me 10 points?

I asked a question and accrued rep at 5 point increments, but never answered one.  Is it possible for a single user to up vote a question twice?  I don't get it.

OR were two users removed and the software reported it as an aggregation?

Full rep history...

[image]

Comment: The question got two views immediately.  Now I am guessing that there is 1 from me, and the software puts the question into the database and this counts as a view.

Comment: @mindcorrosive, there may be someone in the higher ups here who knows and is willing to share.  Can we wait until the question has about 22 - 23 views before migration?  The question is not the end of the world for me, not urgent; I just don't get how the system worked out what it did.

Comment: Maybe two users were removed and the system joins the reputation delta.

Comment: @JoErNanO Unless something has changed recently, only the reputation tab is joining user deletion events, not the dropdown as in the OP's question.

Comment: could you have two questions? If the single user upvoted them both, then was removed, you would lose more rep. I've lost up to a hundred at a time.

Comment: You sure you never answered a question? It might have been long ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A single user did not give you 10 rep points on [your question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15930/how-does-email-communication-with-a-private-pilot-affect-faa-rules-on-compensati), there were 2 users who were deleted approximately about the same time that both had upvoted it.

The "User was removed" is showing an aggregation of both users being deleted.

Comment: Also related: [Who is this user, who has been removed?](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1698/who-is-this-user-who-has-been-removed)

Comment: So I was right? Ha! :)